# Change Ajax Url call Dynamically onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to dynamically change the **Ajax URL**, this is what I have done so far :

```
var size=1;
var from = 1;
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){

    if(e.wheelDelta<0 && from<5){
        from++;
    }
    else if(e.wheelDelta>0 && from>1){
        from--;
    }
    console.log(from)
});

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/api/v1/users?f="+from+"&s="+size,
   data: { get_param: 'value' },
   dataType: 'json',
```

With the `mousewheel` event I change the value of "**from**", with this variable I can concatenate the string `/api/v1/users?f="+from+"&s="+size`, to form a URL.

The variable works fine when I give `mousewheel` event-listener, but doesn't change the Ajax URL.

Any tips?

Comment: add the full code

Comment: call ajax inside event handler

Comment: put your ajax inside eventListener

Comment: Ok, I set the event listener for the ajax call, but still can't edit ajax url live

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is not right, your scroll code block change the value of `from` when scrolling is done. But when page loads the `ajax` call initiates with the initial value of `from`.

So to solve this you have to call ajax inside event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly i think following will help you.

You need to move the ajax call inside the event listner to get the values of from in ajax call

Here is my solution based on the code you provided.

```js
var size = 1;
var from = 1;
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if (e.wheelDelta < 0 && from < 5) {
    from++;
  } else if (e.wheelDelta > 0 && from > 1) {
    from--;
  }
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/api/v1/users?f=" + from + "&s=" + size,
  data: {
    get_param: 'value'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {}
})
});
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, the code work but repeat in infinite loop witout scroll and always calls the same contents